# How to check Internet Connection in Java ME?

Tags: java-me, gprs, httpconnection

I am developing a Java ME Application. Here I am doing `HttpConnection` as follows,

```
HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open( url.trim() );
```

Variable url is an valid url. Sometimes because of unavailability of GPRS Connection, I am getting error in HttpConnection Error. So can I check that my `HttpConnection` is done or not ?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @casperOne, It was IOException, as no network was available.

Comment: I'm not the one who closed it, but from my point of view, it doesn't show what the error is (that's usually critical in determining what's happening).  I can see you're trying to create a canonical resource, but this reads more like a general guide on how to get the response details and not an actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getResponseCode()` & `getResponseMessage()` of `HttpConnection`'s API for the checking of Successful Connection.

`getResponseCode()` will return integer value 200 which means it is successful connection with server. 404 means Page not found.